# Deceleration of Vehicle off pavement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, momentum, friction

How would I calculate the deceleration of a vehicle ([ATV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-terrain_vehicle)), wheels locked, on dirt? How long would it take to halt? How fast is it decelerating?

I used [this](http://www.csgnetwork.com/stopdistcalc.html) calculator, but it seems incorrect for a light vehicle.

Comment: ^I might add that our vehicle is under 700lbs, and a max speed of 35mph. Also, according to that calculator, no matter what the mass, a vehicle going 35mph will stop in about 62 feet (.7 COF)...does that mean a train will stop in 62 feet as well?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16286/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9888/2451

Answer (score 1):

The calculator assumes a constant coefficient of friction which is probably a good approximation within a certain range of weights for rubber tires on a hard surface.  For a train, metal on dirt would probably have a very different coefficient of friction, and also the weight of the train would likely deform the surface, so this analysis would not apply.  Likewise, for a vehicle stopping wheels locked on a soft dirt surface, there will be a digging in effect which will be different than stopping on asphalt.

Comment: Before we start fights over this again, perhaps it would be better to call it the coefficient of *rolling* friction?

Comment: @AlanSE: The wheels are locked.

Comment: I don't see why the coefficient of friction model should work for dirt. You need to measure, it might be strongly velocity dependent.